# neo4j - Importing CSV practise, Get one of the header from hearders

Tags: neo4j

I am new to Neo4j, I am learning it by following the Nicole White's video on the Neo4j official website. In the video it has a part that:

```
Load CSV WITH HEADERS FROM
'file:/Users/Consumer_Complaints.csv' AS line
WITH line.'Date received' AS date
Limit 1
return date
```

When I do the same thing, it shows me errors, showed as figure:

```
Invalid input ''': expected whitespace or a property key name (line 3, column         11 (offset: 83))
"WITH line.'Date received' AS date"
```

Could someone tell me why is that? And how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the backtick `` ` `` instead of the single quote in the property name.

```
Load CSV WITH HEADERS FROM
'file:/Users/Consumer_Complaints.csv' AS line
WITH line.`Date received` AS date
Limit 1
return date
```

Change `'Date received'` to `` `Date received` ``.